# Site to Site to Site VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, site-to-site-vpn

Just wondering if this is possible, we have a leased cisco 2911 (That I do not have access to) at that is set up with a site to site VPN to tie into a third party's Active Directory server.

Our other locations is a mix of netgates and site-to-site to the central office, that I would like to replace with our own equipment.

What I am planning to to is put a new router in the central office network and create a new VPN structure with our own routers (either 1921's or 2911's) so I can send VLAN's over the VPN without involving a third party.

I want to make sure I can tie the daughter stores into the third party's Active Directory server though the main store.

I have seen a few site-to-site discussions that were under a NAT but they were the the DHCP server as well, I just want to make sure my plan will work before I order 10 routers.

[image: Main location and Daughter location]

Comment: Sorry what?  It isn't at all clear to me what you are asking here.  I suspect your answer though is just add the correct routes in the correct places.

Comment: What is a "main store"? And where did 1921's come into the explanation of your setup? DHCP shouldn't have anything to do with site-to-site VPN's, and NAT should be irrelevant as well unless 2 (or more) of the sites use the same address space. Summary: edit your question to give us (a lot) more details.

Comment: added more detail, thanks for the responses, as long as I have everything correct on my end, the Third party will only  have to add the routes to their interface correct?

Comment: This should be possible right?